# Azure mobile services PullAsync(query) not filtering records

Tags: azure, windows-phone-8, azure-mobile-services

I'm new in windows phone and azure mobile services. I want use in my application azure offline data, but I have one problem with PullAsync(). I don't want pull all data to the local database. I want filter data.

I try use PullAsync() like this:

```
await App.rateTable.PullAsync(App.rateTable.Where(a => a.user_id == userId));
```

It's not working and I get bad request message.

user_id is not primary key.
Is there any way to filter data before pulling all to local database?

Comment: That should be working, the above code should send a query to the server like: /table/rate/$filter=(user_id eq '<value of userId>').  I would start by using a tool like postman to verify the query shown above works just hitting the server.  If so, then verify the types of your user_id property and your userId variable are correct and match what the server is expecting.

Answer (score 0):

More information can be found on [this msdn forum thread](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/azure/en-US/4ac5220f-e809-49dc-b9fa-3319edde4b19/mobile-services-offline-pullasync-only-retrieves-data-where-updatedat-date-the-latest-record?forum=azuremobile&prof=required).

The following will retrieve all records the first time, and after that only updated records:

```
await App.rateTable.PullAsync("userId", 
                               App.rateTable.Where(a => a.user_id == userId));
```

The first parameter is the queryKey. This is used to track your requests to the server. Note that the queryKey is restricted to 25 alphanumeric characters, and excludes hyphens, whitespace, etc. From the linked thread: `the query key should just be a descriptor of the query`.

Comment: See also https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/azure/en-US/da1e81c0-4437-4ecd-a1cb-c8745faef522/breaking-change-in-mobile-services-offine-sync-version-13?forum=azuremobile